# New questions clear the text from search box

Tags: bug, new-nav, live-refresh

There seems to be a bug related to the search box and live-refresh of new questions.

To reproduce, type in something in the search box and wait for a new question to pop-up in any of the tabs.

[image]

When a new question is posted on any of those tabs, the search box gets automatically cleared. It gets replaced with the list of tags applicable to the current tab.

[image]

I had observed this issue about a couple of weeks ago, and then today again.

Also, I recall checking this with the old Nav, and it is there for old Nav as well.

Comment: It happens for me even after I move the focus out of the search box.

Comment: Those arrows are disturbingly straight.